# Swift SpriteKit '($T15) -> $T16' is not identical to 'SKEmitterNode'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am new Swift

I get this error: `'($T15) -> $T16' is not identical to 'SKEmitterNode'`

From this code:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let untypedEmitter : AnyObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Explosion", ofType: "sks")!)!
    let emitter:SKEmitterNode = untypedEmitter as SKEmitterNode
    emitter.position = Player.position

    self.addChild(emitter)
    emitter(runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1), SKAction.runBlock(emitter.particleBirthRate = 0)])))
}
```

The error is on the last line

Screenshot:[image: image of error in XCode]

I am running XCode version 6.2

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax for calling the `runAction` method on the node. It should be

```
emitter.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1), SKAction.runBlock({emitter.particleBirthRate = 0})]))
```

Note the change from `emitter(runAction( ... ))` to `emitter.runAction( ... )`.

**Edit**

Also note that there was no block passed to `runBlock`. It should be

```
SKAction.runBlock({ /* code in here */ })
```

instead of just

```
SKAction.runBlock( /* just code here wouldn't be inside of a block/closure */ )
```

Comment: It worked but now i get a new error `Could not find and overload for 'waitForDuration' that accepts the supplied arguements`

Comment: That's is a very unhelpful error, seeing that the problem is in the other action (runBlock). I've edited the answer